# Firefox crashing when application is switching to a new method

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am getting an "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException" error, and I am not sure how to fix it in this situation. The application will get through the set up and start opening Firefox, but then Firefox crashes on the next step.
The program is supposed to check if the Glassfish server is still working when logging in to our site.

```
run:

setUp

testExample
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at spidamin.Example.testExample(Spidamin.java:32)
    at spidamin.Example.main(Example.java:68)
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 8 seconds)
```

Program:

```
package example;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class Example {

    private WebDriver driver;
    private String baseUrl;
    private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
    private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("\nsetUp");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        baseUrl = "http://example.com/";
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Test
    public void testExample() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("testExample");
        driver.get(baseUrl + "/portal/web/guest"); <------------------- Line 32
        driver.findElement(By.name("_58_login")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.name("_58_login")).sendKeys("kyle.hoover@example.net");
        driver.findElement(By.id("_58_password")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("_58_password")).sendKeys("password here");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type=\"submit\"]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("You are signed in as"));
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sign Out")).click();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("tearDown");
        driver.quit();
        String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
        if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
            fail(verificationErrorString);
            Process i = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start \"C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Tests\\Test.bat\"");
        }
    }

    public boolean isElementPresent() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("isElementPresent");
        try {
            System.out.println("True");
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("You are signed in as"));
            return true;
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            System.out.println("false");
            Process i = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start \"C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Tests\\Test.bat\"");
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Example().setUp();
        new Example().testExample(); <------------------- Line 68
        new Example().isElementPresent();
        new Example().tearDown();
        System.out.println("\nprogram finished");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    new Example().setUp();
    new Example().testExample(); <------------------- Line 68
```

In the first statement you create a new `Example` object and call `setUp()`.

In the second statement you create a ***second*** new `Example` and call `testExample()`.  In this second object, `setUp()` has not been called so `driver` is still null, resulting in the exception.

What you want to do is

```
Example ex = new Example();
ex.setUp();
ex.testExample();
ex.isElementPresent();
ex.tearDown();
```

Comment: Eacj time you execute `new Example()` you create another new instance of `Example`.